# Unable to save the captured photo in hololens app

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm attempting to capture a photo inside my `hololens` app. It is working but it saves the image in device portal. I want to save the image in hololens app so that I can see it in my photos on the hololens. I have given the filepath as

```
string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.Path, filename);
```

for storing the photo in hololens app but here I am getting error:

> the name WINDOWS does not exist in the context.

Please anyone help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to save captured photo in photos folder -hololens unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564177/how-to-save-captured-photo-in-photos-folder-hololens-unity)

Comment: Does it matter if this is for hololens v1 or v2?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an if/endif statement to your file path variable since the Windows namespace only exists on the HoloLens and not in Unity. Something like this:

```
#if WINDOWS_UWP
    filePath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.CameraRoll.Path, filename);               
#endif
```

Also don't forget to enable the Pictures library permission under the Player settings